# UILocalNotification badge wont come off

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Im using UILocalNotificaion to send push notifications to the user but im facing a problem that the little 1 number above the app icon wont come off.
Does anyone know how can i fix it?

this is the code of the notification:

```
    let fire = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
    localNotification.fireDate = fire
    localNotification.alertBody = textsArray[Int(randomNum)]
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotification.repeatInterval = .weekOfYear
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    APP.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Comment: Remove this line `localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1` or try with `localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`

Comment: @MidhunMP thank you, fixed it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your AppDelegate, go into ApplicationDidBecomeActive method and add

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

That way, every time the user opens the app (if its a new open or it was open from the background, this will fire and reset the badge

Answer (score 0):

> the little 1 number above the app icon wont come off. Does anyone know how can i fix it?

You don't show any code that *makes* the number 1 "come off". But *you* are the one who put the badge on. It won't magically "come off" by itself. If you want to remove it, *you* must remove it.

You can readily do this at any time by setting the shared application's `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to zero.

Comment: I wanted it to come off when the user presses on the app or on the notification